# How to use web workers (ngx-web-worker) in angular?

Tags: angular, diff, web-worker

I want to diff two large texts so I decided to use diffjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff). Unfortunately it was too heavy for the javascript process and made the page useless for more than 15 seconds.

I have an angular application so I decided to try out ngx-web-worker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-web-worker) may it helps. At the end probably I don't understand this implementation of web workers because it does not run. :(

Minimal example:

```
import * as diff from 'diff';
import { WebWorkerService } from 'ngx-web-worker';

@Component({...}) ... {
  constructor(
    private _webWorker: WebWorkerService
  ){}
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
        this._webWorker.run(diff.diffTrimmedLines, this.texts).then((result) => {
          let changes:number = 0;
          result.forEach((part) => {
            if(part.added || part.removed){ changes++; }
          });
          console.log(changes);
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks your help and time in advance. :)

Comment: Is diff.diffTrimmedLines pure function; without any dependencies.
There should not be any instance or plugin dependencies inside your method.

Something like _.find() or angular functionality

Comment: I found the code at https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/src/diff/line.js and at https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff/blob/master/src/diff/base.js but as I see it does not use any dependencies so it should work.

Comment: Ok. Seems like there is something because I got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: diff__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__ is not defined"

Comment: You can use @angular/service-worker (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

Answer (score 0):

I added this to assets in the angular.json:

```
{ "glob": "diff.min.js", "input": "node_modules/diff/dist", "output": "assets/js"}
```

This way I will get the script in my assets folder after the build. Next I changed my code:

```
this._webWorker.run((input:any) => { 
   importScripts(`${input.protocol}//${input.host}/path/assets/js/diff.min.js`);
   return Diff.diffTrimmedLines(input.texts[0], input.texts[1]);
 }, {
    texts: texts,
    protocol: window.location.protocol,
    host: window.location.host
 }).then(...);
```

So with importScripts I could load the js from the assets.

Hope this helps for others :)

Answer (score 0):

[Angular official doc](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker#adding-a-web-worker)

To add a web worker to an existing project, use the Angular CLI ng generate command.

```
ng generate web-worker <location>
```

The command performs the following actions.

- Configures your project to use web workers, if it isn't already.
- Adds the following scaffold code to src/app/app.worker.ts to receive
  messages.

  > addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  > const response = "worker response to ${data}";
  > postMessage(response);
  > });
- Adds the following scaffold code to src/app/app.component.ts to use the worker.

> ```
>   if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
>   // Create a new
>   const worker = new Worker('./app.worker', { type: 'module' });
>   worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
>     console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
>   };
>   worker.postMessage('hello');
> } else {
>   // Web workers are not supported in this environment.
>   // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
> }
> ```